# WSO2 - Manage - Add Data Service - Oracle ( The "Data Sources" page does not appear - is empty)

Tags: oracle, wso2, store

Trying to set-up a Oracle data source from the WSO2 Management Console. My problem is that the page where one would enter the connection details (url, username etc) shows up empty, there are no fields/columns.

From the Tools section - Database Explorer - I can connect to the database and retrieve data so I'm assuming that the drivers are ok.

Have tried to set-up the data source with several different browsers but all behave the same - I can enter the "Create Data Service" - page 1 and give a name to the data store. Then comes up the second page, titled "Data Sources" and there is the text/link "Add New Data Store". Clicking that open a new page (addDataSource.jsp) but it is totally empty, now even a single header or anything, only a help button on far right corner.

The version of DSS is 3.2.1.

Would someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Are there any errors printed to DSS_home/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log ?  If so, they would help troubleshoot this.

Comment: Hi,

after trying all kind of things the issue was resolved today. It would appear that Java SDK 1.8 was causing the problem, when I changed to version 1.7 things started to work as expected.

I did contact WSO2 two and it was perhaps their comment - "check the stack" - that made me to try WSO2 in another environment that had Java SDK 1.7 and it worked ok.

So, not quite sure if this is the root of the problem, but if anyone else has the same issue I would recommend to check first the version of the SDK.

Thanks